# How can i convert from JSON to Array of Strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using mui-datatables for ReactJS using Material-UI,
It requires the data to be array of string. but our current WS is returning a JSON object.

**current data:**

```
data = [{"Name":"Joe James", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Yonkers", "State":"NY"},
{"Name":"John Walsh", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Hartford", "State":"CT"}];
```

**data required:**

```
data = [["Joe James", "Test Corp", "Yonkers", "NY"],
 ["John Walsh", "Test Corp", "Hartford", "CT"]];
```

Comment: Neither is JSON. The latter is also an "array of array", which might be odd. Regardless, the *actual* question might be: "How can I extract all the *values* from an object?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Array.map & Object.values to produce your needed data

```js
datas = [{"Name":"Joe James", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Yonkers", "State":"NY"},
{"Name":"John Walsh", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Hartford", "State":"CT"}];

const result = datas.map(Object.values);
// Or for more clear 
//  const result = datas.map(data => Object.values(data));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can reduce that to `datas.map(Object.values)`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one:**

```
data = [{"Name":"Joe James", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Yonkers", "State":"NY"}, 
{"Name":"John Walsh", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Hartford", "State":"CT"}];

result_data = [Object.values(data[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a array of javascript object and use Object.values() to extract the values

```
var data = data = [{"Name":"Joe James", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Yonkers","State":"NY"},
{"Name":"John Walsh", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Hartford", "State":"CT"}];

data.map(x => Object.values(x));
```

Result is shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

have a look at this

```
var data = '[{"Name":"Joe James", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Yonkers", "State":"NY"},{"Name":"John Walsh", "Company":"Test Corp", "City":"Hartford", "State":"CT"}]';

var parseData = JSON.parse(data);

var newthing = [];
for (var x in parseData) {
   newthing.push(Object.values(ph[x]));
}
console.log(newthing);
```